# Find basis and dimension of sum and intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Just have to make sure that I understand things correctly so I have four vectors:

$$\textbf{a}_1 = \langle 1,2,0,1 \rangle \\ \textbf{a}_2 = \langle 1,1,1,0\rangle \\ \textbf{b}_1 = \langle 1,0,1,0 \rangle \\ \textbf{b}_2 = \langle 1,3,0,1 \rangle$$

1.

I found basis and dimension of sum this way:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 &1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

so dimension of sum is $3$ where $\langle \textbf{a}_1, \textbf{a}_2, \textbf{b}_2 \rangle$ are basis sum vectors

2.

I found basis and dimension of intersection this way:

$$\alpha_1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \alpha_2\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \beta_2\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 0 $$

and transfered it to the following linear equations:

$$\begin{cases}\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - \beta_2 = 0 \\ 2\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - 3\beta_2 = 0 \\ \alpha_2 = 0 \\ \alpha_1 - \beta_2 = 0 \end{cases}$$

solved it using Gaussian elimination I got one zero line and clear identity matrix was left.

Am I right about workflow? Or are there mistakes?

Comment: What do you mean by "I found basis and dimension of sum this way..."?

Comment: @Jack, put all 4 vectors into the matrix and applied Gaussian elimination to get row echelon form

Comment: What texts are you following? I have never seen the phrase "dimension of sum" before. "Dimension" is a concept for *vector spaces*.  Same issue with "dimension of intersection".

Comment: One needs to specify "sum" of what spaces and "intersection" of what spaces in order to understand your question.